# How to open new activity with different name on app bar in navigation drawer

Tags: android

When click on gallery of navigation drawer a new activity whose name is gallery on app bar has to be open with same hamburger icon and all the stuff that are on main app bar.

Comment: Please elaborate your question...

Comment: use fragments and keeo a single activity and switch between your views or you need to do a way around to have nav bar and drawer in other activities

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

I hope this help you...

Comment: you are using fragments for navigation drawer, right?